# Gutenberg Editor: display error with a combination of transform and background-attachment:fixed

Tags: css, block-editor, front-end

For the output of post content, the main column is constrained to 700px. This allows for images etc. to be aligned left and right whilst remaining within the content column.

Adding a solution using a combination of `left` and `translateX` to “stretch” the width of elements marked with `.alignwide` or `.alignfull` outside the containing column works fine. However, when the element - e.g. a Cover Block - is marked with the class name `has-parallax` to allow a background image with `background-attachment: fixed`, the background image is also transformed relative to the browser window and hence cropped.

Does anyone understand why this is the case, or have a solution? A very simplified example of this occurrence is in this Pen: https://codepen.io/permanenttourist/pen/LYVZOpN?editors=1100

Comment: is this a frontend issue or a block editor issue? If this is an issue in stock Gutenberg you can raise a GitHub issue to get it resolved

Comment: Frontend. I've since found a better solution, which uses negative margins to “stretch” the elements in question. The Codepen at https://codepen.io/permanenttourist/pen/LYVZOpN?editors=1100 is updated with the improved solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've since found a better solution, which uses negative margins to “stretch” the elements in question. The Codepen at https://codepen.io/permanenttourist/pen/LYVZOpN?editors=1100 is updated with the improved solution.